# JQuery selector: pass on id from array into function

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a list of items

```
<div id="item1">somestuff</div>
<div id="item2">somestuff</div>
<div id="item3">somestuff</div>
```

When someone clicks on one of these, I need to take some actions based on the id (the number). Let's say hide it.

How can I make the function generic, and how can I pass the id into the function?

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#item-howcanImakethisselectorgeneric?").click(function () { 
  $("#item-andhowcanIpasshteidintohere?").hide();
}
}
```

I'm a javascript/jquery newbie, any help (including rtfm) appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> <div id="item1" class="mygenericClass">somestuff</div>
>
> <div id="item2" class="mygenericClass">somestuff</div>
>
> <div id="item3" class="mygenericClass">somestuff</div>
> ```

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
  $(".mygenericClass").click(function () {  
    //if you want the id then $(this).id
    //if you just want to hide the clicked element then
    $(this).hide(); 
  }); 
}
```

Comment: Perfect. How can I get the id without the "item" text, ie. just the number?

Comment: var justTheNumber = ($(this).id).replace("item", "")

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<div id="item1" class="stuff">somestuff</div>
<div id="item2" class="stuff">somestuff</div>
<div id="item3" class="stuff">somestuff</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $("#item1, #item2, #item3").click(function () { 
     $(this).hide();
   }
}
```

or even better:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $("div.stuff").click(function () { 
     $(this).hide();
   }
}
```

or this if you will be dynamically adding more divs into the page after loading and don't want to explicitly add the event handlers

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $("div.stuff").live("click", function () { 
     $(this).hide();
   }
}
```

Comment: if you need to get the actual text of the id within the function, you can use "this.Id"

Comment: awesome. And to get only the number, so not "item1" but just "1"?